# Automatic Rows & Columns with CSS

Tags: css

I have ~170 small, square elements in a div, I'd like them to arrange themselves into however many rows they need to for the width of the div (which will change with the width of the browser).

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
</div>
```

I know I could do:

```
#container .sq { float:right; }
```

with some padding to make them collect on the right and slowly overflow downwards - something like this:

```
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
      . . . .
```

where each dot is an `sq` element, but I really want something that overflows *upwards*, so they'd look like this:

```
      . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

or like this if the browser was resized:

```
    . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
```

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible in CSS?

Comment: Is the size of each of the `div` s known?

Comment: It'll be a % of the screen width, so not explicitly (in CSS anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty in implementing that probably vastly outweighs the desire for the result. You may be able to achieve it using JavaScript/jQuery but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort?

Comment: I think you're probably right, HTML is findamentally top-to-bottom in structure, javascript would probably be the only way and it's undoubtedly too much for the effect!

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you need?

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/smart-columns-w-css-jquery/

Comment: Great link, but the `sq` elements will be a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

In IE8, you can say [`-ms-writing-mode: rl-bt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531187%28VS.85%29.aspx). Although `writing-mode` is part of the [CSS3 Text Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text-layout/) work, this value is not included in the draft spec at this time.

On all other browsers you would need some script. For example if each `.sq` had `float: right;`, you could add `clear: right` to every nth element starting from the end of the list. (Where n is the number of squares that you calculate will fit the width.) Or simply `float: left;` and add a `margin-left` to the first sq to push it however far to the right it needs to be.

Comment: Appreciate the IE8 tip there, but I'm aiming for cross-browser support (as I work on a mac!) - I think I'll find a different layout, as the scripting seems like overkill.